# Does echo and print not work in the 'live' version of php?

Tags: php, json, printing, echo, messenger

So I'm quite new to programming, and I have nothing else to describe it but a live script, so please correct me with the official term. Anyway, a while ago, I made this bot in php and ran it locally in my browser using xampp on my mac. I could very easily use echo and print_r to print arrays and whatever to the webpage. The script would only run if I reloaded the page, so this is what i'm talking about as 'not live'. Now I have started trying to make a messenger bot in PHP, and i'm using cloud9. I also see the script in a browser, but here, I can only see products of echo and print if they are simple strings I have entered, for example:

```
print_r("stack overflow is life");
```

This will print as expected in my browser. However, this is where me talking about 'live' script runs comes into play. Instead of reloading the page, it runs live. The messenger bot will always be active on the server, and it instantly replies to a message sent to it as wanted. I use this code:

```
/* receive and send messages */ 
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
file_put_contents("fb.txt", file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo ("<pre>");    print_r($input);
echo ("</pre>");
```

Now, in this case, the `$input` is not printed. I see nothing. Now I don't know if this is to do with live server  response, or what, but I need to know how to see this is the browser. And I have tested to see if there actually is a successfully converted JSON to array, because I am able to use the info in `$input` to reply to my facebook messaged and the bot works. I can also output the JSON to a txt file, and see it there, but there is no `<pre>` tags so it is hard to read, and I want the nice clean array to see in the browser. All code revolves around this, so it is very important.

Comment: Whatever calls this file needs to display what is returned from this file, AJAX maybe?

Comment: A good mantra: "what changed?"

As for `live` / `not live`... could we call these 'environments'?  i.e. dev/staging/production?  Sure there is some difference from doing everything on localhost vs over the net.  Honestly this might be more to do with input stream changes around 5.6.  Finally, agree with Theo that web sockets are the *right* way to do this these days.

Comment: @ficuscr I think live means that it rather than see it after a refresh he wants to see it instantly not the "my project went live" more "live tv"

Comment: You need to look up server-side code vs client-side code. Essentially PHP cannot update the client without a request/response. If you want to see php information without re-submitting or re-freshing you need to look into JavaScript/jQuery for Ajax support.

Comment: yeah... was under impression you had something that worked at one point.  If that is not the case then you need to understand basic request/response nature of HTTP.  Then expand reading up on AJAX / comet / long poll, then graduate to web sockets.  You are making a bit of a leap.

Comment: haha ok will do

Comment: I don't think you fully understand me. I am getting the json fine. I just cannot print it to the browser window or echo it. I defo know i'm getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

So you are writing the raw input to the file and json decoding it separately. So it is quite possible you are not actually getting valid json.

If you do pass invalid json, `json_decode` returns `NULL` which is why you see that when you `var_dump` - so you have to call `json_last_error` to be sure it worked.

From Docs:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
>
> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

You should really check if `json_decode` works, here is an example to demonstrate:

```
<?php
$badjson = '{bad:"json"}';
$decoded = json_decode($badjson);
if(json_last_error()!==JSON_ERROR_NONE){
    echo "Json Decode Failed: ".json_last_error_msg();
}else{
    var_dump($decoded);
}

echo "\n---\n";

$goodjson = '{"property":"value"}';
$decoded = json_decode($goodjson);
if(json_last_error()!==JSON_ERROR_NONE){
    echo "Json Decode Failed: ".json_last_error_msg();
}else{
    var_dump($decoded);
}
```

See it in action here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a07e57f4cd01bd63d2945d5e367bbb0a6158195

See PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

You can use a syntax checker to find the problem with your json e.g. http://jsonlint.com/

A common issue if the json is manually created is failing to wrap properties in  double quotes e.g. `{property:"value"}` is invalid while `{"property":"value"}` is valid.

Note the reason you have to check `json_last_error`, and can't rely on `NULL` meaning it failed is because `json_decode('NULL');` would return `NULL` and that would be correct.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what is cloud9.

For debug you can try var_dump() function. It will print onto your browser data type and data values, because there could be different type of "nothing". It's not a better way for debugging but a naive one. For better: check debug and breakpoint possibilities in this cloud9.

var_dump() can eat as many arguments as you like, so it's handy to dump everything with php input too to check what comes and how it changes.

Comment: Yes, I have tried var_dump(), it only prints out /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:22:
NULL

Comment: I don't think it's the data type thats the problem, I have printed out 'non live' arrays in php before just fine